# Reading stdio.h file

Tags: linux, gcc

I have compiled my C program in linux using gcc and saved all the temporary files. In .i file, stdio.h file has been expanded. I have been trying to read it but i could not understand the meaning of few initial lines.

```
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "app.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 313 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/predefs.h" 1 3 4
# 314 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 346 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 353 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 354 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 347 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
```

I think the number after # symbol is line number but what is the significance of 1,2,3,4 at the end of every line? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ohh sorry i found it,

Comment: those are flags  1 - Start of a new file
2 - Returning to previous file
3 - Following text comes from a system header file (#include <> vs #include "")
4 - Following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, then!